# Reading AppLink data with Unity3D on iOS and Android

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, applinks

We are are trying to add AppLinks to our Facebook self hosted Open Graph objects. I've added the required meta tags and now one of our Unity developers is implementing it in our Android and iOS mobile clients.

We aren't able to find documentation on how to read the AppLink data with Facebook Unity SDK. The docs are pretty clear on iOS and Android Facebook SDK's but Unity seems to only have the Deep Link functionality (superseded by AppLinks for iOS and Android) which just reads the og:url metadata instead of the e.g.: al:ios:url metadata

We also can't find anything on applinks.org about Unity. It states for iOS and Android to use the Bolts framework which is included in the Facebook iOS and Android SDK's.

Our Unity developer says he can't include the Bolts framework because it conflicts with the Facebook Unity SDK.

Is there a solution to fix this or do we have to recode our Facebook SDK implementions for our specific Android and iOS builds?

Comment: Did you find out anything regarding this? I'd also like to use AppLinks with the Facebook SDK for Unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I talked with some Facebook developers at F8 earlier this year. Facebook basically gave up on Unity before. But after they resolved their problems with Chrome, Unity is back on the table and they will start building a new SDK

Comment: I'm looking at a similar problem, I want to parse the JSON string and store values in playerPrefs. But your answer to your question isn't helping me. Can you share your progress in term of implementation? have you actually got an answer / success?

furthermore I need a code solution for Unity such that when I build for either iOS or Android everything is done already such as .plist or manifest settings for myAppName:// schema respectively. reason is I plan to start using Unity cloud build ... in other words I don't want hours of pain in xcode and eclipse again and again.

Comment: Basically, we are at the mercy of Facebook... Our Unity developer found a way to "hack" it and make it work for either OS by looking at the Android and iOS SDK's.

They were pretty vague about the Unity SDK at F8 though. And I still haven't heard anything about it. So either they gave up on it again or they ran into some serious problems. (I'm guessing the former as Facebook should have enough manpower and knowledge to have this done within one month)

Comment: seems iOS and Android handle UnitySendMessage differently in Unity, ask your developer to PM, I have iOS working but Android partially working, trying to find a document on the inconsistency at the moment.